# How can i fix the git?

Tags: git

I  dont know how to fix the problem.
I Want to delete all the file but always tell me the command is not expect!
[image]

Comment: Please do not post text as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it directly as text into the question. Also what does this have to do with C?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a normal git error message - is this from a course?

Comment: Yes,it is from the course.

Comment: Sorry my english is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, your `grade` command is insisting you have a fully committed repo. It states quite clearly that only files committed and pushed to main will be graded so it's obviously got some check to ensure this has been done.

That would mean doing a git add followed by a git commit (and possibly a push as well), assuming that you're happy with the changes you have made:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'my code'
git push
```

Then try to run `grade` again.